# Block conversion from VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

We have a large development team, and was wondering if there's a method to configure VS2010 to block conversion of VS2008 projects to VS2010.  The goal is to ensure that folks don't make a potentially large mistake by converting projects that should remain on VS2008.   Folks could use VS2010 to work on solutions originally created in VS2010 only.  One or two people on a team may be appointed as the ones who can do the conversion.

I've done a bit of searching hoping to find a registry key to enable this functionality, but so far no luck.

In an ideal world folks would be experienced enough to not make this kind of problem, and TFS will definitely ensure there's a recovery path, but it would be nice if we use studio to help prevent this from becoming an issue.

Comment: Wouldn't an email that says, "Hey, don't do that" to the development team suffice?

Comment: :) I was hoping the 'in an ideal world...' would address these types of completely reasonable process responses.  Looking for a technical way to assist what we'll do process wise.

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way to do this, short of denying commit access to your project files.  Of course I'm not sure of any reason NOT to convert the projects, unless maybe some of your team doesn't have VS2010 yet, as you can continue to target 3.5 and still use VS2010.

Comment: We're about to ship a product and want to minimize risk; we thought a good way to do this would be to exploit the side by side capabilities of VS2008 & 2010.  We'd rather work out the kinks of moving to a new version of VS for the next major release, vs being under pressure when a production defect is found.

Comment: Fair enough.  Sadly, I don't know of anything that can help you, except my suggestion of locking down source control.